# AWS Beanstalk errors on Ruby on Rails deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to deploy the Ruby on Rails application on AWS Beanstalk and getting an error from `checkforraketask.rb`.

Application Details

Ruby version: 2.7.6

Rails Version: 6.0.3.7

I can successfully deploy the application to Heroku. I can successfully run it locally. But I cannot deploy to Beanstalk. The way I set up BeanStalk is, that I created the Beanstalk application, RDS PostgreSQL, and added PostgreSQL as an environment variable.

The error is saying, that the Beanstalk script requires 'rake' but it cannot find the rake. Is there something I can do to resolve this issue?

snippets for eb-engine.log

```
2022/06/29 18:30:21.953393 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c rbenv global
2022/06/29 18:30:21.963953 [INFO] 2.7.6

2022/06/29 18:30:21.963973 [INFO] Running command /bin/su webapp -c bundle exec /opt/elasticbeanstalk/config/private/checkforraketask.rb db:migrate
2022/06/29 18:30:22.208796 [INFO] bundler: failed to load command: /opt/elasticbeanstalk/config/private/checkforraketask.rb (/opt/elasticbeanstalk/config/private/checkforraketask.rb)
/opt/elasticbeanstalk/config/private/checkforraketask.rb:16:in `require': cannot load such file -- rake (LoadError)
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/config/private/checkforraketask.rb:16:in `<top (required)>'
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.7.6/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.7.0/bundler/cli/exec.rb:58:in `load'
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.7.6/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.7.0/bundler/cli/exec.rb:58:in `kernel_load'
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.7.6/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.7.0/bundler/cli/exec.rb:23:in `run'
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.7.6/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.7.0/bundler/cli.rb:483:in `exec'
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.7.6/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.7.0/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.7.6/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.7.0/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.7.6/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.7.0/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.7.6/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.7.0/bundler/cli.rb:31:in `dispatch'
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.7.6/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.7.0/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:485:in `start'
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.7.6/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.7.0/bundler/cli.rb:25:in `start'
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.7.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.3.15/exe/bundle:48:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.7.6/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.7.0/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:117:in `with_friendly_errors'
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.7.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.3.15/exe/bundle:36:in `<top (required)>'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/.rbenv/versions/2.7.6/bin/bundle:25:in `load'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/.rbenv/versions/2.7.6/bin/bundle:25:in `<main>'

2022/06/29 18:30:22.208819 [INFO] No db:migrate task in Rakefile, skipping db:migrate.
2022/06/29 18:30:22.208825 [INFO] Executing instruction: configure log streaming
2022/06/29 18:30:22.208831 [INFO] log streaming is not enabled
2022/06/29 18:30:22.208835 [INFO] disable log stream
2022/06/29 18:30:22.208845 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl show -p PartOf amazon-cloudwatch-agent.service
2022/06/29 18:30:22.223812 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl stop amazon-cloudwatch-agent.service
2022/06/29 18:30:22.229124 [INFO] Executing instruction: GetToggleForceRotate
2022/06/29 18:30:22.229136 [INFO] Checking if logs need forced rotation
2022/06/29 18:30:22.229149 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c /opt/aws/bin/cfn-get-metadata -s arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-2:436400436229:stack/awseb-e-kpppqjtjp3-stack/6632ba10-f19e-11ec-92df-02bd2192b5ec -r AWSEBAutoScalingGroup --region us-east-2
2022/06/29 18:30:22.526852 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c /opt/aws/bin/cfn-get-metadata -s arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-2:436400436229:stack/awseb-e-kpppqjtjp3-stack/6632ba10-f19e-11ec-92df-02bd2192b5ec -r AWSEBBeanstalkMetadata --region us-east-2
2022/06/29 18:30:22.831876 [INFO] Generating rsyslog config from Procfile
2022/06/29 18:30:22.833583 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl restart rsyslog.service
2022/06/29 18:30:22.851257 [INFO] Executing instruction: PostBuildEbExtension
2022/06/29 18:30:22.851280 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c rbenv global
2022/06/29 18:30:22.863615 [INFO] 2.7.6
```

I have 'rake' gem included on Gemfile too but I am still seeing that error.

Comment: Install your gems in your eb environment.

Comment: same problem here

Comment: did you ever resolve this? running into the same thing